# Flurry Analytics: how is time spent defined?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

Time spent shows 249,311 in my Flurry Analytics dashboard. I have no clue what unit this is in, maybe minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the metrics section of Flurry time spent is reported in seconds:[image]

Within Explorer the time spent is reported in milliseconds:
[image]

Can you post a screenshot showing where you are seeing the 249,311 value?

Comment: That time is reported in Seconds. We'll work to get that labeled properly.